# Android Hide and Show Actionbar when Scrolling up and down

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to hide and show the Actionbar when Scrolling up and down my activity. I'm following some tutorials on CoordinatorLayout, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/menuTheme"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.musicplayer.mp3player.activities.FragmentDrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the code that I use to setup the action bar.

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: https://labs.ribot.co.uk/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32#.45k164x5s

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager should be a direct child of CoordinatorLayout because it has a behavior, change the layouts' tree as:

```
DrawerLayout

   CoordinatorLayout

      AppBarLayout

         ...

      /AppBarLayout

      ViewPager (with behavior)

   /CoordinatorLayout

/DrawerLayout
```